BigQuery - How to count the number of digits after decimal for a float value
In BigQuery table, I have a column with FLOAT data type. I need to format the value in this column to have 3 digits after decimal, but only if the value itself has less digits after decimal than 3. In case the value has 3 or more digits after decimal, the value needs to be displayed as is.
For that purpose, I'm trying to count the number of digits after decimal for each value in the column. How do I do that?



Input_Column
Output_column




2
0


1.123
3


1.12
2




SELECT LENGTH(SUBSTR(FORMAT('%t', column1), INSTR(FORMAT('%t', column1), '.') + 1)) AS DIGITS_AFTER_DECIMAL
FROM table1

